# Criando Migration JAVA para adicionar perfil de usuário ao PostGreeMysql Através do ANGULAR

Tags: java, angular

```
/*Início Vaviaréis PERFIL_PFL*/

DECLARE @idUserAdmin INT
DECLARE @idMenuPermissaoPfl INT
DECLARE @idPCPERFIL INT
DECLARE @codigoPCPERFIL VARCHAR(10) = 'PCPERFIL'
DECLARE @recurso VARCHAR(25) = 'form-com-manutencao'
DECLARE @rota VARCHAR(150) = 'formulario-perfil-pc'
DECLARE @nomeMenu VARCHAR(50) = 'Formulário Perfil PC'

/*fim Vaviaréis PERFIL_PFL*/


BEGIN


/*início Inserir Perfil PERFIL_PFL se não existir*/
    BEGIN
          IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ACESSO_CONTROLE.PERFIL WHERE CODIGO = @codigoPCPERFIL)
          BEGIN
                INSERT INTO ACESSO_CONTROLE.PERFIL (DESCRICAO, CODIGO, CRIADO_POR)
                VALUES ('PCPERFIL', @codigoPCPERFIL, @idUserAdmin)
                SET @idPCPERFIL = CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() as int)
          END
          ELSE
          BEGIN
                SELECT @idPCPERFIL = ID_PERFIL
                FROM ACESSO_CONTROLE.PERFIL
                WHERE CODIGO = @codigoPCPERFIL
          END
    END
/*Fim Inserir Perfil PERFIL_PFL se não existir*/



/* Início Pega o id do usuário admin */

 BEGIN
                SELECT DISTINCT TOP 1 @idUserAdmin = U.ID_USUARIO
                FROM ACESSO_CONTROLE.USUARIO as U
                INNER JOIN ACESSO_CONTROLE.USUARIO_PERFIL PM on U.ID_USUARIO = PM.USUARIO_FK
                INNER JOIN ACESSO_CONTROLE.PERFIL P on P.ID_PERFIL = PM.PERFIL_FK
                WHERE P.[CODIGO] = '1'
                ORDER BY U.ID_USUARIO
        END

/* Fim Pega o id do usuário admin */



/*início Declaração da rota do menu*/

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ACESSO_CONTROLE.MENU WHERE DESCRICAO = @nomeMenu)
BEGIN
UPDATE ACESSO_CONTROLE.MENU
SET ROTA = @rota
WHERE ROTA IS NULL
END

/*fim Declaração da rota do menu*/




/* Início permissão do perfil e menu */
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO ACESSO_CONTROLE.PERFIL_MENU_PERMISSAO (PERFIL_FK, MENU_PERMISSAO_FK, CRIADO_POR)
        VALUES (@idPCPERFIL, @idMenuPermissaoPfl, @idUserAdmin),

    END

/*Fim permissão do perfil e menu */


END
```

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: Vou usar angular e aplicar essa Migration ao banco da empresa, esse código deveria adicionar um usuário e  as permissões de menu ao banco de dados. mas, quando rodo ele quebra. já analisei e não consegui encontrar o problema, o banco é Postgree, o sistema é Java

Comment: Precisamos de parte do código onde o problema ocorre e o erro que está ocorrendo pra ajudar, ou o erro ocorre nessa procedure?